# CAPTCHA with street signs

Tags: support, captcha

For this specific CAPTCHA:

[image: CAPTCHA image]

Do you select the square that has a tiny little bit of sign in it? On similar CAPTCHAs, sometimes the square is *just* a sign post, often split among (up to) 4 blocks.

Do you select the sign posts?

Comment: You should select all squares with a piece of the street sign, so that would be (top to bottom, left to right): 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13

Comment: Nice try, robot

Comment: @PatrickHofman Wouldn't it be 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 13 14? Squares 9 10 13 14 contains the octagon that is also some kind of a sign.

Comment: @iBug The octagon is a stop sign, though, not a **street sign**. There's only six squares with an actual piece of a [street sign](https://www.google.com/search?q=street+sign&tbm=isch) in them (1 2 3 5 6 7). The rest are just sign posts or other kinds of signs.

Comment: Humans know that a corner of a street sign is still part of that street sign, even if it does not contain data relating to determining one's current position and or determining the course to one's ultimate destination.  Robot scum.